# Symfony 3 - Doctrine wrong query structure - multi tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with Doctrine woring in my Symfony project.
That's my code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Factory\MainBundle\Entity\Lastauction;
use Factory\MainBundle\Entity\Offers;

class AuctionListController extends Controller
{
    private $em;    
    private $qb;
    private $offer;

    public function getAuctionListAction()
    {
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        getAllAccount();
        for($offset=0; $offset<20000; $offset++)
        {
            $this->insertOffers();
        }   
        return new Response('Offers list generated');
    }   

    private function getAllAccount()
    {
        $this->qb->select('ac.mail')
            ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Account', 'ac');
        $result = $this->qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        $this->accounts = array_column($result, 'mail');
    }   


    private function insertOffers() 
    {
        foreach($this->offers as $id => $offer)
        {
            if($this->checkIfExsistOffer($offer))
            {
                echo $offer .'<br>';
                $offerObj = new Offers();
                $offerObj->setOffer($offer);
                $offerObj->setPage(2);
                $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $this->em->persist($offerObj);  
                if (($id % $this->batchSize) == 0) 
                {
                    $this->em->flush();
                    $this->em->clear();
                }   
            }
        }
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear();
        $this->offers = array();
    }   

    private function checkIfExsistOffer($offerUrl)
    {
        $this->qb->select('o.id')
            ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Offers', 'o')         
            ->where("o.offer=:offer")
            ->setParameter('offer', $offerUrl);
        $result = $this->qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return (isset($result['0']['id'])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

And I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 134 near 'o WHERE o.of': Error: 'o' is already defined.
>
> [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 134 near 'o WHERE o.of': Error: 'o' is already defined.
>   [1/2] QueryException: SELECT o.id FROM FactoryMainBundle:Account ac, FactoryMainBundle:Lastauction la, FactoryMainBundle:Offers o, FactoryMainBundle:Offers o WHERE o.offer='123'

Why Doctrine takes tables from other queries?

Comment: Without any context (eg. your class mappings and the rest of your querybuilder) there's really nothing we can tell you. Except: Why would you use your variables inside your DQL instead of parameters and binding them?

Comment: I updated my post. I have hope that now is enough code to analyze.

Comment: You are always using the same querybuilder object and just adding to it's `?
`select from`-tables.

Comment: Yeah, it is the answer :) Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakdown of your codeflow regarding `$this->qb`:

1) In `getAuctionListAction`: `$this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();`

2) In `getAllAccount`:

```
$this->qb->select('ac.mail')
         ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Account', 'ac');
```

3) In `checkIfExsistOffer` (through `insertOffers`), 20.000x due to your loop in `getAuctionListAction`:

```
$this->qb->select('o.id')
     ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Offers', 'o')
     ->where("o.offer=:offer")
     ->setParameter('offer', $offerUrl);
```

Long Story short: You're adding multiple tables to your `$this->qb` querybuilder object (through `$this->qb->from(...)`), that's why they all get queried.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->qb->select('o.id')
        ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Offers', 'o')
        ->where("o.offer=:offer")
        ->setParameter('offer', $offerUrl);
    $result = $this->qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Good job on suggesting the use of parameters in queries. However, you might actually want to write a sentence or two as to **why** OP should do that. Especially since it doesn't solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
private function checkIfExsistOffer($offerUrl)
{
        $res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FactoryMainBundle:Offers')
            ->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->select('o.id')
            ->where("o.id=:offer")
            ->setParameter('offer', 1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult(); //return single result 

        var_dump($res);die; //test
}
```

Comment: You might actually want to write a sentence or two in your answers. Also: Why wouldn't you edit this into your previous answer? This might solve OPs problem in this case (since it's creating a new QueryBuilder) but it doesn't explain to him in which way his code is wrong (so he can avoid it in the future).

Comment: @ccKep, I am so sorry, my English is very baad :)